# android Layout issue: button doesnt show properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am developing a shopping webview app for my college project. But my app home screen have some issues in some mobile devices.

I need the following layout

|Button| <--->|Logo(Big)| <--->|Button|

|              Text              |

Please heck my layout xml and please suggest me edits.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="7dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="#fff">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SignOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="314dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        android:capitalize="characters"
        android:foregroundTint="#7E63DC"
        android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Sign Out"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#7E63DC"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        android:capitalize="characters"
        android:foregroundTint="#7E63DC"
        android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="HELP"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#7E63DC"
        android:textSize="15sp"></Button>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logopng" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="371dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Welcome to our app, Please select any of the options "
        android:textColor="#7e63dc"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can use ConstraintLayout

Comment: Your parent's `layout_height` is only 7dp. Not much is going to appear on the screen if you're only giving it 7dp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all your parent `RelativeLayout` shoud have bigger height or `wrap_content`, and `layout_weight` does nothing (is for `LinearLayout`), so remove it

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff">
```

for both `Button`s remove below lines, beause of `wrap_content` height of `RelativeLayout` parent and because`alignParentEnd` will align both `Button`s to one side (usually right, on RTL devices to left)

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

next, for left `Button` add

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

and for right `Button` add

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

at the end center your `ImageView` with this line

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

or this

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

and remove these lines

```
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

your text `View` should be placed outside and below `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed review.

But, I have to inlude a grid layout below this one
then what you suggest?

Comment: then I would suggest keep this text inside `RelativeLayout` and set `android:layout_below="id_of_layout"` for it, more info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative#Position). pick `id` of `View` with most height - when you align to `Button` and your logo will have more height then part of it will be covered by text from yout `TextView`